# Mathematica plotting based on all previous equation results

Tags: graph, plot, wolfram-mathematica, equation

I have a plot 
`Plot[40500*x^(-0.1), {x, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 50000}]`

I'm trying to plot the cumulative of these y values. I'll try to explain with an example:

I'm trying to get

```
for x=1: 40500*1^(-0.1) 
for x=2: 40500*(2^(-0.1)+1^(-0.1)) 
for x=3: 40500*(3^(-0.1)+2^(-0.1)+1^(-0.1)) 
and so on up to x=100.
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There is a [SO site for mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Look at the examples in the documentation for FoldList and see if that can do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running some examples for `x = 3`

```
for x=3: 40500*(3^(-0.1)+2^(-0.1)+1^(-0.1))
```

> ```
> 114574.
> ```

This can be found using `Sum`:

```
Sum[40500*i^(-0.1), {i, 3}]
```

or using `Fold`

```
Fold[#1 + 40500*#2^(-0.1) &, 0, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> 114574.
> ```

`FoldList` outputs the intermediate steps.

```
FoldList[#1 + 40500*#2^(-0.1) &, 0, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {0, 40500., 78287.8, 114574.}
> ```

Accumulating to 100 and discarding the initial zero value:

```
ListLinePlot[Rest[FoldList[#1 + 40500*#2^(-0.1) &, 0, Range[100]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that what I needed is actually called Integrate. I'm dumb, I spent so much time searching for the answer to my question.